# have a hat like John

Tags: comparison, comparative

Could a be used to mean b?

> a. Sam has a hat like John.

> b. Sam has a hat like John's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Some people will tell you it's not "precise" or make jokes like "But John isn't like a hat". But in ordinary language use, the [pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics) tell you what is meant, and the sentence is perfectly normal.

Comment: How about "Sam's hat is bigger than John"?

Comment: No, that one doesn't work. I think because _bigger_ is a more precise relationship than _like_.  Perhaps part of the answer is that _like John_ can be interpreted as qualifying "has a hat".

Comment: Just to be sure, do you think the sentence in question is correct in ordinary language, not an accidental mistake?

Comment: Yes I think it's perfectly normal. It is potential ambiguous: it could also mean "Sam has a hat just as John has", without implying that the hats are similar (though I think there is likely to be a comma after _hat_ in that sense). But the most obvious meaning is the one you want.

Answer (score -3):

tricky one to answer ..
well, lets say the first one is still a better construction if one has to choose.
But otherwise not so impressive way of writing. In the first case, the last verb has been omitted or considered obvious, so omitted. ( verb: has)
Sam has a hat like John **has**.

Second is inferior. The possessive should not be the last word- that too dangling without a noun.

Both are grammatically okay, but not preferred :).